# how to get dynamic v-model in vue js and request that in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am quite new in vue js and **I've a v-model which comes from v-for now I want to request it from the controller but it always gives me null**
Here is mu input field

```
<input type="text" :name="keyword.id" :v-model="form['field'+keyword.id]" class="form-control input_form" :value="keyword[$route.params.langCode]">
```

and in the data property

```
data(){
            return {
                allModules: [],
                key: '',
                keywords: [],
                form: new Form({
                    moduleId: '',
                    field: []
                })
            }
        },
```

and here is my method

```
saveTranslate(){

                    this.form.post('/admin/systemsetting/saveTranslate/').then((response) =>{
                        console.log(this.$route.params.langCode)
                    })


            }
```

and in my controller, I like to request all like this

```
return $request->all();
```

but i always get this
[image]

Comment: Try taking the `:` before `v-model` I don't think that is valid syntax. Also what you are doing is not really dynamic it's just not there. right away but it doesn't seem like it's changing.

Comment: but it is already there please look and if you have any better solution please share

Comment: I just suggested a solution remove the `:`! Have you tried that?

Comment: if i remove then it caught this error  ":value="keyword[$route.params.langCode]" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally"

Comment: you can't use `-v-model` and `:value` on the same element. All v-model is, is a shrotcut for `:value` and `@input="updateValue"`